# How to detect if a specific version of vcredist_x86.exe has already been installed?

Tags: visual-studio, nsis, detection, vcredist

I created an installer that run vcredist_x86.exe (version 9.0.x.x) as part of the installation. Before installing it however I would like to know if it's already in the user's system. I basically need to detect not only that the DLLs are present but that they have the right version number. Is there any reliable way to do that?

I'm using NSIS but any solution would be welcome.

Comment: Don't go there, just run it.  Vcredist is really meant for end-users.  As long as you have an installer, the better mousetrap is to use the merge modules from C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to follow your advice. I don't seem to have this merge module anywhere. Could you tell me what is does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that, so I ended up always installing the package whether it's already installed or not. Since it's a small install anyway it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
!include "x64.nsh"

Section
  var /GLOBAL hasCRT
  !define CRTCHECKDLL msvcr80.dll
  !define CRTCHECKNAME 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.6195",type="win32",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"'
  push '${CRTCHECKDLL}'
  push '${CRTCHECKNAME}'
  call WinSxS_HasAssembly
  pop $hasCRT
  DetailPrint ${CRTCHECKDLL}=$hasCRT
SectionEnd
```